# Separation of variables help

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Use separation of variables to solve the Differential Equation:

$$
K \frac{dN}{dt} = -r(N-K)(N-A).
$$

After doing partial fractions and the integration I get:

$$
\frac{(N-A)}{(N-K)}= C_1 e^{(A-K)(-rt)/K}
$$
I am stuck solving for $N$.

Comment: I have not checked your calculation. We have $N-A=(N-K)M(t)$ where $M(t)$ is the mess on the right-hand side. So $N(1-M(t))=A-KM(t)$. Divide both sides by $1-M(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \begin{align}
\frac{x-a}{x-b}&=c \\
\implies  x-a &= cx-cb \\
\implies  x(1-c) &= -cb+a \\
\implies  x &= \frac{a-cb}{1-c}
\end{align} $$